FATAL EXCEPTION: main Unable to start service com.asterinet.react.bgactions.RNBackgroundActionsTask
When switching from RN 0.71 to 0.74 and, accordingly, API 33->34, a problem arose

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.compassionclips, PID: 30138
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.asterinet.react.bgactions.RNBackgroundActionsTask

I updated for help with this https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.71.3&to=0.74.2
but i get no work version - when I run the application I get(when work background serveces) "Keep stoping"
my MainActivity.kt
package com.goapp

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.fabricEnabled
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
// import android.app.PendingIntent;
// import android.app.Service;
// import android.content.Context;
// import android.app.Intent;
// import androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat


class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {
  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  override fun getMainComponentName(): String = "GoApp"

  /**  
  * добавление типов уведомлений 
  */
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel("notification", "avengers")
            createNotificationChannel("cancel", "cancel_order")
            createNotificationChannel("order_ready", "order_ready")
        }
    }
  
   private fun createNotificationChannel(channelId: String, soundFileName: String) {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId, 
            "goapp", 
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).apply {
                setShowBadge(true)
                description = ""
                val att = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build()
                setSound(Uri.parse("${ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE}://${packageName}/raw/$soundFileName"), att)
                enableVibration(true)
                vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(400, 400)
                lockscreenVisibility = NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
        }
        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
//if i add this -> BUILD FAILED
            // if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            // startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification)
            // } else {
            //         startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification, 
            // FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK)
            // }
            // 
    }
  
    
  override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate =
    DefaultReactActivityDelegate(this, mainComponentName, fabricEnabled)
}



this my AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>


    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


     <!-- <service
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
       android:exported="true"
     /> -->
<!-- if add this also -> BUILD FAILED  --> 
...

what am I doing wrong, please help 

API level 34 or higher requires the declaration of service type for all foreground services. The type depends on the functionality of the service. Something like this:
<application ... >
  ...
  <service 
    android:name="com.asterinet.react.bgactions.RNBackgroundActionsTask" 
    android:foregroundServiceType="shortService"/>
  ...
</application>

See Declare foreground services in your manifest and INSTALL.md for details.

thanks, it's work❤️.  Otherwise I’ve already racked my brains, but it turns out that what needs to be written in it is the error text
